# aurelia custom element date - nifty datepicker update value on update

Tags: javascript, aurelia, bootstrap-datepicker

I have created a custom element (date.html/date.js). This is working great barring if I use it on a edit page. It has already binded the object (selected value = '') then it returns a db object (my edit data) from the DB, I need at this point to re-bind the selected value.

I had this issue with another custom element I created (a dropdown), I solved the issue by adding 'selectedChanged', this then re-binded after it had been to the database.

My issue is, I've tried selectedChanged and added a debugger (its never hit), I am thinking thats because I should be using something else, but I don't know what?

```
selectedChanged(){
    // if chosen item isnt = selected then set it
    var currentSelected = $('select', this.element).find(':selected').val();
    if(currentSelected != this.selected) {           

            $('select', this.element).val(this.selected);
            $('select', this.element).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
}
```

**date.js**

```
import {customElement, bindable, inject, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
    import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';
    import $ from 'jquery';

@customElement('date')
@bindable({name: 'value', attribute: 'value', defaultValue: '', defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay})
@inject(Element)
export class Date {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.pickerDate = '';
    }

    bind(){
        var options = {
            autoclose: true, 
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        };

        $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker(options).datepicker('update', this.value);

        $('.input-group.date', this.element).on('changeDate', (event) => {           
            this.value = $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker('getUTCDate');
        });
    }
}

**date.html**
<template>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled.bind="readonly" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i></span>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm not really front-end js etc so dont know what call its expecting?

Comment: I don't really understand your question...  What's not working?

Comment: My date input area isn't re-rendering after its undertake a call to the DB, meaning when the page is loaded (on EDIT), its blank

Comment: I agree with @MathieuLeblanc the question is vague. Please change it to be more specific about the problem, not just a bunch of related and not-so-related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note my @bindable object (for the date input box) is call 'value' therefore under the constructor I have added 'valueChanged()'

FULL CODE:

```
import {customElement, bindable, inject, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';

@customElement('date')
@bindable({name: 'value', attribute: 'value', defaultValue: '', defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay})

@inject(Element)
export class Date {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.pickerDate = '';
    }

    valueChanged() {
        var currentvalue = $('.input-group.date', this.element).val();

        if (currentvalue !== this.selected) {
            $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker('update', this.value);
        }
    }

    bind(){
        var options = {
            autoclose: true, 
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        };

        $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker(options).datepicker('update', this.value);    

        $('.input-group.date', this.element).on('changeDate', (event) => {           
            this.value = $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker('getUTCDate');
        });
    }
}
```